# If a multipier is just connected adders, why is it even considered a multiplier?

Tags: assembly, architecture

What is the point of a [binary multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier) if it's just a collection of binary adders? In other words, why just not have more binary adders and call them a multiplier? Is a multiplier somehow faster than just the adders?

In a sense is this how it works: if an operation is common enough, they take it out of software and give it its own dedicated (specialized) hardware unit for doing it(e.g. multiplication) and it can do it much faster?

Comment: Multipliers calculate the result of multiplying two numbers together. If you want to multiply two binary numbers together in hardware you need a binary multiplier. That's the point. Adders don't multiply numbers together, they just add.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as because the answer is in the wiki article linked, and not particularly obscure.  It doesn't need to be cluttering up SO.  Clearly it wasn't obvious to the OP, or he wouldn't have asked though :/

Answer (score 1):

Well that is basically what the binary multiplier  is.  But those adders are arranged to do the multiply.  If you didnt arrange them and just had more adders you would have to have software connect them basically and what would be the point of that?  You can do that now with the basic add and shift available.

Yes it is definitely faster, you can approach a multiply in one clock, where if you were to do the shifts and adds on separate clocks like you might in software or like the good old days, then it can take many clocks, approaching one or two times the number of bit width of the operands.

This was all in the wikipedia article you linked, so not sure why you are asking here.

The cost trade off for the performance gain is chip real estate.  Naturally you could balance that by say having a half sized one and burning more clocks but not N or 2N (or more) number of clocks.  Instead maybe 4 or 8 or so...